# Oracle SQL Developer 'cuts off' characters on lines in SQL Worksheet

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This issue is difficult to describe without a picture, so I included one below.

Essentially, Oracle SQL Developer will 'cut off' or 'drop' characters in the SQL worksheet.

Here is some text (123456789123456789123456789123456789;) displayed in both Notepad and the SQL worksheet.

[image: 1to9 being cut off oracle sql developer sql worksheet]

You can see above that the final 8 and 9 are overlapping.

Is there a known fix for this? I have tried changing back to the default theme, but the same issue persists.

Thanks,
Vaughn

EDIT: Here is the actual text, copied from SQL Developer: 123456789123456789123456789123456789;

Also, since I'm sure it will be asked, my version is 18.2.0.183, and the build is 183.1748

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWikK.png - SQL Developer Build 17.089.1709. Are you sure there is no unicode character between last 8 and 9?

Comment: please include the ACTUAL text - I have the same question as @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Included actual text.

Comment: what font are you using? it works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you increase font, does it help?

(tools > preferences > code editor > font )